# inverse of preservation of intervals theorem

Tags: real-analysis

is inverse of preservation of intervals theorem true?
preservation of intervals theorem is true so I have this question if map of every interval by f still be an interval can f be continuous?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider $f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin \frac 1x,&x \ne 0\\0,&x = 0\end{cases}$.